# Stop listening to hover events for a certain time period

Tags: javascript, event-handling, zooming, fullpage.js

I am using [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js) (which you can see in a demo [here](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage)) in combination with a image-zoom (on hover) plugin.

The problem is that when I move to a new slide on fullpage, and the cursor happens to (quickly) pass over an image during the slide animation,  the image zoom sometimes gets activated and after the animation stops, an enlarged portion of the image (from the previous slide) is still visible until I move the cursor again.

Also, I only have a minified version of the zooming plugin so can't address this from there, however, fullpage.js provides various callbacks, so maybe one solution could be to "freeze" listening to hover events for as long as the animation lasts? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two quick options:

1. You could set CSS "pointer-events: none" on the `<body>` when fullpage is switching to a new slide, then remove that style after the slide transition is finished. However this won't work on IE10 or lower.
2. You could have an absolutely positioned empty div in the body that covers the entire view at a z-index above everything else. Attach mousemove/mouseover/mouseout event listeners to that div and have those listeners cancelbubble and preventDefault on any event they receive. This will cause that div to eat any mouse events that could cause a hover. Keep that div display:none until there is a slide transition. Set display:block on slide transition.

Comment: Solved it by observing in web inspector what the zoom plugin does. It creates a "zoom-viewer" div when over an image. So, I just set `display: none` on that div in the onSlideLoad callback. However, your first suggestion helped to fine-tune it, so no zooming occurs during the actual animation. Thanks